Using a stored in Azure ChromaDB instance with Python client
I have set up a Azure WebApp in order to use a ChromaDB instance to store some data. I want to use python to add documents, make queries, etc.
I am currently doing :
import chromadb
from chromadb.config import Settings
client = chromadb.HttpClient(
    host=url,
    settings=Settings(
        chroma_client_auth_provider=CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_PROVIDER,
        chroma_client_auth_credentials=bearer_token
                      )
)

My url is https://....azurewebsites.net", and settings parameters are stored in my azure instance ENV variables.
It seems to not appreciate my login parameters :
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[23], line 3
      1 import chromadb
      2 from chromadb.config import Settings
----> 3 client = chromadb.HttpClient(
      4     host=url,
      5     settings=Settings(
      6         chroma_client_auth_provider=CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_PROVIDER,
      7         chroma_client_auth_credentials=bearer_token
      8                       )
      9 )

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\chromadb\__init__.py:204, in HttpClient(host, port, ssl, headers, settings, tenant, database)
    201 settings.chroma_server_ssl_enabled = ssl
    202 settings.chroma_server_headers = headers
--> 204 return ClientCreator(tenant=tenant, database=database, settings=settings)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\chromadb\api\client.py:56, in Client.__init__(self, tenant, database, settings)
     50 def __init__(
     51     self,
     52     tenant: str = DEFAULT_TENANT,
     53     database: str = DEFAULT_DATABASE,
     54     settings: Settings = Settings(),
     55 ) -> None:
...
    118         "Both credentials file and credentials found."
    119         "Please provide only one."
    120     )

ValueError: No credentials file or credentials found in [chroma_server_authn_credentials].

What am I doing wrong ? Is there another way to connect via Python ?
Thank you

The error indicates that both CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_CREDENTIALS_FILE and CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_CREDENTIALS are defined, which is causing a conflict. ChromaDB requires only one set of credentials to be provided at a time.
Steps to Resolve
Remove Redundant Environment Variables
You can either use Basic Authentication or Token-Based Authentication, but not both. Depending on your choice:
Option 1: Basic Authentication
Set only these environment variables:
export CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_CREDENTIALS_FILE="<path_to_server.htpasswd>"
export CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_PROVIDER="chromadb.auth.basic_authn.BasicAuthenticationServerProvider"

Remove the following:
unset CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_CREDENTIALS
unset CHROMA_AUTH_TOKEN_TRANSPORT_HEADER

Option 2: Token-Based Authentication
Set only these environment variables:
export CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_CREDENTIALS="test-token"
export CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_PROVIDER="chromadb.auth.token_authn.TokenAuthenticationServerProvider"
export CHROMA_AUTH_TOKEN_TRANSPORT_HEADER="X-Chroma-Token"

Remove the following:
unset CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_CREDENTIALS_FILE

Source Your Environment File
After making these changes, ensure the environment variables are loaded:
source ~/.bashrc  # or ~/.zshrc depending on your shell

Verify the Variables Confirm that only the necessary variables are set:
echo $CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_CREDENTIALS
echo $CHROMA_SERVER_AUTHN_CREDENTIALS_FILE

Ensure only one of them returns a value.
